# what does passing lambda in urlconf in django mean?

Tags: django, lambda, django-urls, django-generic-views, url-pattern

I came across this `code` in`Djangobook`. I am not able to understand what this means.

```
urlpatterns=pattern('django.views.generic',
                   url(r'^$','simple.direct_to_template',
                   kwargs={
                         'template':'index.html',
                         'extra_content':{'item_list':lambda:Item.objects.all()}
                          }
                   )
```

And in the template, simple iteration to display the items

```
{% for item in item_list %}
```

What is the purpose of `lambda` in the above url?

P.S: I know how `lambda` works in `python (anonymous function)`. But I want to know what purpose it serves here. Why not have `'extra_content':{'item_list':Item.objects.all()}`, since that will produce `iterable` anyway.

EDIT:

if i have

```
info_dict={'queryset':Item.objects.all()}
```

and pass this `dict` to `extra_content`

```
'extra_content':{'item_list':queryset}
```

would it be the same as `lambda` (I have seen this kind of example in the djangobook}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'extra_content':{'item_list':Item.objects.all()}
```

will be evaluated when the URLconf is loaded, so `item_list` will contain the same items for every request. Using a lambda tells Django to call that lambda for every request, meaning that `items_list` will change as new `Items` are added, removed, or edited in the database.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: I'm actually not sure. I'd just a lambda, but give your approach a try and see what happens.